# Phaser 3 - Custom animated cursor not working

Tags: phaser-framework, mouse-cursor

I tried implementing a custom animated cursor. I used the line `gameState.idle.setInteractive({cursor: 'url("assets/pet.cur"), pointer'});`. The same line worked when the cursor wasn't animated, but once I made it an animated cursor, it only would load the pointer cursor.

Is there any way to use animated custom cursors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a **phaser** problem, this is a issue of the browser(s). As far as I know browsers don't support animated cursors. There are some workarounds, but all methods are hacky and might not work well under high load.

But if you really want to do it, here is an article describing a possible solution/approach https://jordaneldredge.com/blog/rendering-animated-ani-cursors-in-the-browser/.
A differnet method would be moving a Sprite to the Mouse position, and hidding the real MousePointer.

**Here a possible, phaser solution:**

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 400,
    height: 200,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update
    }
};

let cody 
var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
    this.load.spritesheet('brawler', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 });
}

function create() {
    this.input.setDefaultCursor('none');
    // some animation
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'walk',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] }),
        frameRate: 8,
        repeat: -1
    });

    cody = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'brawler').setOrigin(.5);
    cody.play('walk');
    
    this.input.on('pointerdown', _ => console.info(_))
}

function update(){
    // update the position
    cody.x = game.input.mousePointer.x;
    cody.y = game.input.mousePointer.y;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense, although that is very unfortunate. I'll definitely check out that sprite option. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @alex I added a small example, how you could solve the problem, with phaser. _(but, it might also create performance issues)_